# Как в Safari в input убрать иконку пользователя?

Tags: html, css, input, safari

В Safari в `input` при редактировании появляется иконка пользователя. Добавление параметра `autocomplete="off"` не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контактную кнопку в Safari можно убрать завязавшись на селектор `::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button`:

```
::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

Можно сделать проще:

```
::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Но в таком случае кнопка остается в потоке поля и может мешать при вводе в него данных.

Comment: Благодарю. Работает, только display: none !important; лишний.

Comment: я рад очень, с наступающим

Comment: И вас! Всего хорошего в Новом Году!

Comment: возможно вы бы смогли мне посоветовать решение по этому вопросу? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631438/