# Почему в поле text при двойном клике предлагает заполнить туда почту?

Tags: html, css

Почему в поле text при двойном клике предлагает заполнить туда почту, но поле совсем не для этого предназначено, как все исправить?

```
<div id="username_fieldset" class="control-prof">
    <label for="user_screen_name" class="t1-label control-profs">Адрес</label>
        <div class="controls-profi">
            <input name="adres" type="text">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="username_fieldset" class="control-prof">
    <label for="user_screen_name" class="t1-label control-profs">Пароль</label>
    <div class="controls-profi">
        <input  name="password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль">
            <p>Введите пароль от вашей учётной записи, чтобы сохранить изменения.</p>
            <div id="list-auth-prof">
               <a id="remindpass">Забыли пароль?</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я скопировал ваш код, у меня все нормально работает =) Не требует заполнить почту!

Comment: На каком-то сайте, где вы заполняли форму, был инпут с таким же атрибутом name.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko сменил атрибутом name, но все равно пихает туда почту

Answer (score 0):

Примините к форме параметр `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<input name="adres" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но этот вариант я пробовал, но он не работает

Comment: @harbor предоставьте полный вариант кода.

Comment: @harbor возможно, вы имеете ввиду эту ошибку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609720/Как-в-safari-в-input-убрать-иконку-пользователя?noredirect=1&lq=1