# Убрать иконку генерации пароля в Safari

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input, safari

Не так давно столкнулся с проблемой, когда [иконка пользователя появлялась в Safari](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609720/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-safari-%D0%B2-input-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). На этот раз появилась другая проблема – иконка генерации пароля в том же Safari, которая портит дизайн `input`. Как избавиться от этой иконки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это iCloud Keychain генерирует такое? обычный `<input type=password>` появляется без какой-либо иконки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот этот псевдоселектор.

```
input:focus::-webkit-textfield-decoration-container {
   visibility: hidden;
   pointer-events: none;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

Если включить отображение `shadow DOM nodes`, то можно увидеть в DOM вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Довольно не маленький список псевдоселекторов можно посмотреть [здесь](https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/aefd6e25064c08e0cc9a).

Comment: Пропадает не только иконка, но и placeholder после такого.

Comment: Во истину, Safari - это новый IE.
Давайте будем убирать иконку только во время фокуса поля ввода.

Answer (score 2):

Решает проблему вот такой сниппет:

```
::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```